# BLE Command Write Issues - iOS

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing this type of command not working on my code.

```
let command:[UInt8] = [0x3A,0x11,0x01,0x00,0x40,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x1e,0x01,0x18,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x58]
let sendData:Data = Data(command)                
cPeripheral.writeValue(sendData as Data, for: txCharacteristic, type: .withoutResponse)
```

Comment: Please explain "Not working"

Comment: when I send this type of command my device not give any output ex. ON/OFF Light

Comment: You must try to narrow down the issue. As it is now, we can't see where the problem lies. Is the device even connected? Do other GATT operations work? Does the GATT characteristic have the "Write without response" property enabled?